# Hide and show dynamic place holder in ng-select angular when user enters text

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am trying to show placeholder in ng select control, but user type something, the placeholder does not hide. I overcame that issue with below code.

```
@Input() placeholder;

ngOnInit() { 
this.searchInput$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(500)
    ).subscribe(term => {
      term?.length > 0 ? this.placeholder = '' : this.placeholder = this.placeholder;
    });
}
```

Html Template:

```
    <ng-select [items]="items$ | async" 
[multiple]="multiSelect" bindLabel="name" 
[appendTo]="appendTo" [placeholder]="placeholder">
```

But when the placeholder is dynamic, this code will reset placeholder to empty string.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css how achived show and hide placeholder

```
   .ng-placeholder {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .ng-select-focused {
        .ng-placeholder {
            display: none;
        }
    }

    .ng-has-value {
        .ng-placeholder {
            display: none;
        }
    }
```